# Cannot accept answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

A user commented

> I am very grateful, it works correctly but I can not give you a public score for not having 15 points on my profile.

On my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/330382/search-customers-in-front-end-by-billing-data/330385?noredirect=1#comment486485_330385).

Is this correct, or are they misunderstanding something about the site? I didn't think there was a threshold for accepting an answer.

Comment: They should be able to checkmark it as accepted.

Comment: If i remember correctly, there's a certain amount of time that the user should wait before marking an answer as accepted, after asking the question. I think it was about 15 minutes, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, the [time limit is 15 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepting an answer is not a reputation-based privilege. Anyone (including a fresh new user having 1 reputation) can accept an answer to their questions as soon as possible by clicking the checkmark icon below the downvote icon. Also, only 1 answer can be accepted on each question.

Looks like the user was mixing ["upvote"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) with "accept", which indeed, is a 15-reputation privilege. Compared to accepting an answer, multiple answers can be upvoted.